# Need to find all client id's the most efficient/fastest way using mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a bridging table that looks like this

```
clients_user_groups
id = int
client_id = int
group_id = int
```

I need to find all client_id's of of clients that belong to the same group as client_id 46l

I can achieve it doing a query as below which produces the correct results

```
SELECT client_id FROM clients_user_groups WHERE group_id = (SELECT group_id FROM clients_user_groups WHERE client_id = 46);
```

Basically what I need to find out is if there's a way achieving the same results without using 2 queries or a faster way, or is the method above the best solution

Comment: Do all clients only belong to one group in your case?

Comment: @various group, a client can only belong to one group

Comment: @Roland, if a client can only belong to one group, I'm confused as to why you have a bridging(cross-reference) table set up between your two tables. Shouldn't `group_id` just be a foreign key in your `clients` table? Perhaps you are looking to make it a N:M relationship later down the road?

Comment: the bridging table was built to accommodate the feature at a later stage to have a client belong to more than one group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `WHERE`-clause subquery which, in MySQL, ends up being reevaluated for every single row in your table. Use a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT a.client_id
FROM   clients_user_groups a
JOIN   clients_user_groups b ON b.client_id = 46
                            AND a.group_id  = b.group_id
```

Since you plan on facilitating clients having more than one group in the future, you might want to add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` so that multiple of the same `client_ids` aren't returned when you do switch (as a result of the client being in more than one of client_id 46's groups).

If you haven't done so already, create the following composite index on:

`(client_id, group_id)`

With `client_id` at the first position in the index since it most likely offers the best initial selectivity. Also, if you've got a substantial amount of rows in your table, ensure that the index is being utilized with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: JOIN is not the quickest approach in this case, because the complexity of your JOIN is quadratic, while having two linear queries (which is still linear) is much more quicker than using a join, note we only need a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a self join also

```
SELECT a.client_id
FROM   clients_user_groups a
LEFT JOIN clients_user_groups b on b.client_id=46 
Where b.group_id=a.group_id
```

Comment: JOIN is not the quickest approach in this case, because the complexity of your JOIN is quadratic, while having two linear queries (which is still linear) is much more quicker than using a join, note we only need a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @groupID = (SELECT group_id FROM clients_user_groups WHERE client_id = 46);
SELECT client_id FROM clients_user_groups WHERE group_id = @groupID;
```

You will have a query which gets the group ID and you store it into a variable. After this you select the client_id values where the group_id matches the value stored in your variable. You can speed up this query even more if you define an index for clients_user_groups.group_id.

Note1: I didn't test my code, hopefully there are no typos, but you've got the idea I think.

Note2: This should be done in a single request, because DB requests are very expensive if we look at the needed time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that each client can only belong to one group, I would suggest a schema change to place the group_id relation into the client table as a field.  Typically, one would use the sort of JOIN table you have described to express many-to-many relationships within a relational database (i.e. clients could belong to many groups and groups could have many clients).

In such a scenario, the query would be made without the need for a sub-select like this:

```
SELECT c.client_id
FROM clients as c
INNER JOIN clients as c2 ON c.group_id = c2.group_id
WHERE c2.client_id = ?
```